# Fitting column heights to first column content

Tags: html, css

I want to create a column layout where the first column shrinks height to fit its content, and the remaining columns are "locked" to that height with `overflow-y: auto` so that if there is too much content it will create a scroll bar.

This is what I have so far, but it obviously doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstcolumn">...variable height content...</div>
    <div id="column">...variable height content locked to height of above...</div>
    <div id="column">...variable height content locked to height of above...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /*height: 300px; <--This solves the issue, but I don't want a fixed height*/
}

#column {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Is CSS Grid an option; with that you have the `min-content` option for sizing which expands to the minimum size necessary to show the content in that grid track. Although, on second thought, that does mean that the second and third columns, if their content is 'larger,' will cause the row to expand to accommodate.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I'm running into. I can hack it a little by letting it draw the first column, then querying the drawn height and setting the wrapper to be that height + margin/padding, but I'd rather have something more elegant that doesn't break when sizes change dynamically.